# How to set browsers tab page title in MVC web application ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am developing MVC application. 
When I run the application I can see the title on the tab of browser as

> Index - My ASP.NET MVC Application.

I want to change it. 
I have used the     `<title> my page</title>` but its not working.

How to set it ?

Comment: just change title of your layout page...

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a view? If you are using the default template project for MVC you're probably doing it in the wrong place, as the title is set by ViewBag.Title, and is rendered by Shared/_Layout.cshtml

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In your view, make sure you have this:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Page";
}
```

In `Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml`, make sure this is there:

```
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
```

Answer (score 5):

Change the Views\Shared_Layout.cshtml. Generally it comes with

```
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.Net MVC application</title>
```